# how to add new data and update existing data in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with multiple fields which I would like to add new rows on a monthly basis as well as update existing customer data.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: The internet is full of examples for that. None of that answered your question? _Why not?_

Comment: Apart from that there obviously is the mysql documentation. Which comes with precise explanations and good examples. That too did not answer your question?

Comment: The question is asked that broad that it is impossible to answer. It basically asks: tell me everything there is to know about working with MySQL databases, data, clients and server.